# CSS Layout-- Make table cell contents appear in row below and set height of parent row/cell

Tags: css, layout

I am modifying a skin for the CKEdit component so that the toolbar is hidden unless clicked.  To do so, I moved the toolbar collapser to the row below it using position: relative and top:18px.

My goal is to have the parent tr of the anchor element a height of 2px, but keep the anchor at 11px.  Is this possible? I cannot alter the DOM, just the styles.

Here's my reduced code

```
<style type="text/css">
    table { width: 80px;}
    td { border: solid 1px #ccc; }
    .header  
    {
        background-color: #99f;
        /* This is being ignored */
        height:2px; 
        }
    .below 
    {
        float: right; 
        position: relative;
        top: 18px;
        /*If I shrink,  the BG image goes Away*/
        height: 11px;
        width: 11px;
        background-image: url('http://ckeditor.com/apps/ckeditor/3.3/skins/kama/images/sprites.png');
        background-position: 4px -1387px;
        border: 1px outset #D3D3D3;
    }
    .hidden { display:none; }

</style>

<table>
<tr><td class="header"><a class="below"><span class="hidden">#</span></a></td></tr>
<tr><td>next row</td></tr>
</table>
```

am reposting new code per the suggestions below.  This shows the arrow at the top right of the page now

```
<style type="text/css">
    table { width: 80px; position:relative;}
    td { border: solid 1px #ccc; }
    .header  
    {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #99f;
        /* This is being ignored */
        height:2px; 
        }
    .below 
    {
        float: right; 
        position: absolute;
        top: 6px;
        right: 2px;
        /*If I shrink,  the BG image goes Away*/
        height: 11px;
        width: 11px;
        background-image: url('http://ckeditor.com/apps/ckeditor/3.3/skins/kama/images/sprites.png');
        background-position: 4px -1387px;
        border: 1px outset #D3D3D3;
    }
    .hidden { display:none; }

</style>

<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<table>
<tr><td class="header"><a class="below"><span class="hidden">#</span></a></td></tr>
<tr><td>next row</td></tr>
</table>
```

**Edit** (per comments):
If I add a relatively positioned div between the anchor and the cell, I can achieve the results, but again, I can't modify the DOM.

```
<td class="header">
<div style="position:relative; ">
    <a class="below"><span class="hidden">#</span></a>
</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `position:relative` on the `<table>` to make absolute positioning in children relative to it. Then add `position:absolute` on the `<a class="below">` and adjust `top` and `left` to your liking. ([see example](http://jsfiddle.net/89jxR/))

```
table { display:block; position:relative; width:80px; }
.header { width:80px; }
.below {
  float: right; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px; right:2px; // adjust as needed
}
```

With the `<a>` positioned absolutely you're free to alter the parent `<td>` height as if it doesn't contain `.below`

EDIT: For it to work in FF needed to add `display:block` to the table and duplicate the `width` in `.header` ([see updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/89jxR/3/))

Comment: same as above:(  It sets the anchor to the top right of the page, not the table.  It's good to know how that works though.  Am I stuck?

Comment: Interesting.  It works in Safari/Chrome.  It doesn't in FF because it doesn't like adding relative position to table elements for some reason.  If I wrap a div around the table and add relative position to that then it works, but obviously that's not a solution for you.  Will see if I can figure something else out, but seems tricky now.

Comment: Nice catch.  I was trying the same thing while you were leaving the comment.  I only tested in Firefox.  It works in IE/Chrome, and as you said, with the shim div in Firefox.  Odd.

Comment: @mVChr Still displays at top right of page in FF.  btw, jsfiddle is a great tool.

Comment: since the actual page was a bit more complicated, I got it to work applying your suggestions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting .below to `position:absolute` instead of `relative` then add `left:69px` (table width - anchor width).

EDIT

```
  td { border: solid 1px #ccc; }
.header  
{
    background-color: #99f;
    /* This is being ignored */
    height:2px; 
    position:relative;

    }
.below 
{
    float: right; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 18px;
    left:69px;
    /*If I shrink,  the BG image goes Away*/
    height: 11px;
    width: 11px;
    background-image: url('http://ckeditor.com/apps/ckeditor/3.3/skins/kama/images/sprites.png');
    background-position: 4px -1387px;
    border: 1px outset #D3D3D3;
}
.hidden { display:none; }
table { width: 80px; position:relative; }
```

and

```
<table>
<tr><td class="header"><a class="below"><span class="hidden">#</span></a></td></tr>
<tr><td>next row</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: works for collapsing the title, but top then becomes relative to the page so I can't set the anchor down to the next row.

Comment: Try setting .header to `position:relative;`

Comment: no dice.  mVChr suggested the same, but to the table.  They're both set to relative now, and the arrow still shows at the top right of the page.  re-posted adjusted code for demo

Comment: If you don't mind setting absolute coordinates, set top:18px, left:69px; the css i put above works for me.

Comment: Actually, Im getting different results in IE. Let me re-tinker. :)

Comment: since the actual page was a bit more complicated, I got it to work applying your suggestions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@CKeditor, you can set the toolbar to startup hidden like so:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {toolbarStartupExpanded : false} );
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm already doing that but it still leaves a 12px header to accommodate the collapse button.  It's that button I'm trying to get into the next row.  Thanks for the tip though:)